# Will I get my reputation back if I cancel my down vote?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, down-votes

Will I get my reputation back if I cancel a down vote? Same for the person I vote down.

Comment: Yes. You will both get the points back. But after 5 minutes the vote is locked. Then you need to hope for the voted post to be edited to be able to change your vote. Or, you can edit it yourself, but it is preferrable to have other reasons for editing the post as well.

Comment: If the person who I down voted deleted the post, what will happen?

Comment: Then you both also get your points back. And, you cannot (un)up/downvote deleted posts.

Comment: Also worth noting is that there is no reputation loss when you downvote a question, or when you downvote a community-wiki answer.

Comment: If you downvote, I urge you to add a reason, otherwise it serves to irritate with little impact and no direction for improvement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will get your points back, and the person you downvoted will also get the points back.